# State type with Pinia is destructed in actions or outside

Tags: typescript, vue.js, store, pinia

Having this store here :

```
interface Task {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  done: boolean;
}

interface TodoState {
  tasks: Task[];
  loading: boolean;
}

export const useTodoStore = defineStore({
  id: 'todo',
  state: (): TodoState => ({
    tasks: [],
    loading: false,
  }),
  getters: {},
  actions: {
    async addTask(name: string): Promise<void> {
      this.loading = true;
      this.tasks.push({ name, done: false, id: generateID() });
      await sleep(200);
      this.loading = false;
    },
  },
});
```

I don't understand why when I hover "tasks" in the action its type is not Task[] but I get

```
(property) tasks: {
    id?: string | undefined;
    name: string;
    done: boolean;
}[]
```

[here is the code in a stackblitz if needed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/boilerplate-vue3-typescript-pinia-r96nwp?file=src%2Fstore%2Ftodo.ts)

The same issue is observed when I get tasks outside of the store. In a component for example.

Comment: First of all, change line tasks: [], -> tasks: [] as Task[], so that this store property has a proper type assigned. However, when hovering tasks in line this.tasks.push(...) the TypeScript parser would still show "any". Sadly, the TypeScript section on the Pinia documentation is very short. Maybe someone else has got a solution.

Comment: The state is already of type TodoState so, it should already knows that tasks: [] is an array of tasks I guess. HHovering line:13 'tasks: []' shows that the type is well recognise at this stage. Otherwise, the typescript does not show 'any' on tasks in the action but a correct type only destructed for some reason I ignore.